# Directing the user to the page he came from after successful registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the following code to redirect the user to the page they came from after successful login. This code has been tested and works correctly:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end', 'actual_referrer' );
 
function actual_referrer() {
   if ( ! wc_get_raw_referer() ) return;
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="' . wp_validate_redirect( wc_get_raw_referer(), wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) . '" />';
}
```

Now, when the user enters my-account from a page for registration, after successful registration, I want to return to the page from which he came, as in the code above.

For this purpose, I found a code that redirects the user to the home page after successful registration:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'customer_register_redirect' );
 
function customer_register_redirect( $redirect_url ) {
   $redirect_url = get_home_url();  
   return $redirect_url;
}
```

Is there a way to edit this code like the login code to redirect the user to the page they came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_registration_url( urlencode( get_permalink() ) );` which after successful registration will redirect to previous page.

In your case since its woocommerce the link to your page should be:

```
<a href="<?php echo wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) . '?redirect_to=' . urlencode( get_permalink() ); ?>">Register</a>
```

Where wp_registration_url is your url to the register page and adding ?redirect_to parameter including the current page.

In your case you can change the code in your filter as:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'customer_register_redirect' );
function customer_register_redirect() {
    $redirect_url = isset( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ? $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] : home_url();
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

In case there is no redirect_to set we gonna redirect to home page or something else as you prefer.

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your help. I tested your code and it keeps redirecting me to the home page. Meanwhile, I am testing my template on `localhost`.

Comment: Also, I apologize for the late reply to your solution because I thought there was no way for this and I waited a long time for a proper answer.

Comment: I have tested it on live and prob something in localhost is the issue. Needs debuging to figure it out i think. Just log your request and see what is giving.

Comment: Hello. After fake registration with a fake email in `localhost`, I am directed to this address: `https://localhost/site/`, which is the address of the home page. If this code works correctly on the real host, the problem is only `localhost`.

Comment: When you click on that button (anchor link) will add the redirect_to parameter otherwise if you are just on registration page will redirect on home page as its empty. Debug when you click on the anchor is it adding the redirect_to parameter in your $_REQUEST its should even if its local host should grab the link